# Why are some useless statements partially allowed?

Tags: c#

I really don't understand why c# compiler allows some useless statements  but disallows some other useless statements.

```
static void Main()
{
    string('a', 1); // useless but allowed
    //"a";// useless and disallowed

    new int(); // useless but allowed
    //0;// useless and disallowed

    new char(); // useless but allowed
    //'\0';// useless and disallowed

    new bool(); // useless but allowed
    //false;// useless and disallowed

    //new int[] { 1, 2 };// useless and disallowed

    //new [] { 1, 2 };// useless and disallowed

    //new int[2];// useless and disallowed

    //new int[2].Length;// useless and disallowed

    int[] var = new int[2]; // useful 
    //var.Length;// useless and disallowed

    string s = string.Empty; // useful
    //string.Empty;// useless and disallowed
}
```

Comment: This doesn't apply to all of these cases, so I'll keep my mouth shut in terms of writing an answer, but in general (not C#-specific): Constructors can have side-effects and thus can be useful to call without storing a reference. This may be bad practice, but it's possible. Writing a no-op like `"a"`, however, is never useful.

Comment: @Excelcius It may be bad practice, but it happens with .NET Framework's own classes. `new Control();` (WinForms) can be a useful statement, as it sets up the synchronisation context as a side effect. Property getters may also have side effects, so `new int[2].Length` could have been allowed for that reason, but somehow wasn't.

Comment: Please give me time to decide the accepted answer. Probably 1-2 days from now. :-)

Comment: @hvd Yes, it may be useful, but it doesn't clearly express the intent. Anyone reviewing the code might remove this line because without any comment or reading the documentation it will look like a useless expression. Using a static method or a singleton describes this situation better and may even be used inside the `Control` constructor to do one-time initialization.

Comment: @Excelcius It's sandwiched between a `Debug.Assert(SynchronizationContext.Current == null);` and a `Debug.Assert(SynchronizationContext.Current != null);` for documentation purposes :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are not "useless" statements. You're calling a constructor, and you don't know what the constructor might do - it may have important side-effects. It may be logging stuff, initializing a connection, etc. Even though it's a bad practice, the compiler can't force you to remove them.

As for your other statements:

- `0`, `false`: integer and boolean literals have no side effects.
- `arr.Length`, properties shouldn't have any side effects (although they may have).

So it's safe to force the developer to remove these statements.

Comment: But calling `new int();` has the same, uncustomized effect forever, so what makes it interesting and special compared to `0;`?

Comment: @TheLastError Even though they produce the same result, `new int()` isn't the same as `0`. `0` is an [integer literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: I think `arr.Length` is a bad example since accessing a getter *could* have side-effects, yet the compiler still doesn't allow to use it as a statement.

Comment: @TheLastError, this might be true, however they are not going to write a 500-line code check to see if specific instance has side-effects or not(or actually writing the class instance side-effect detection algorithm). TLDR: you're right, there's something that can be done, however C# guys have 1000x more important things to work with. It would be also major source of confusion: why can I initialize some type like that, and can't others?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the difference between, for example, `new int();` and `0;`? What does the compiler do when processing each of them?

Comment: @TheLastError as far as I know, it's just a syntactical difference. I suspect they will be parsed in different ways, but compiled in the same way. I don't have the time now, but you could easily check the produced IL to verify this.

Comment: @TheLastError Another aspect worth noticing: you *can* initialize a const int with `new int()`, even though const fields must be initialize with constant expressions. That's why I suspect the compiler will treat `new int()` as the corresponding constant (`0`). But as far as the syntax analyzer knows, these are two different expressions. Anyway, there are simply my thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

These statements are not useless, you just don't store their values.
But you can write for example

```
Console.WriteLine(new int()); // output: 0
```

Calling a constructor is a valid statement which creates a value, the problem is that you don't assign this value to any variable so it's not available later.

Comment: It does not answer my question I think. :-)

Comment: This is a bit different, it does store the value in the parameter passed to WriteLine for the duration of the method execution.

Answer (score 2):

Method and constructor calls are allowed, because they can have side effects.

Other things don't, because they don't have side effects (or *shouldn't*, as in the case of properties).

Answer (score 2):

Writing a literal like `0;` as a statement is not allowed because

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Obviously that doesn't explain why the C# compiler team didn't allow the use of literals like that but I would imagine that it is either because

- creating the parser or compiler was easier that way
- it removed a source of potential problems or bugs

The reason why `new ClassName();` is allowed as a statement without storing it into a variable is that constructors can introduce side-effects which might be what the developer wanted to do. Disallowing such a construct would mean the developer had to introduce a meaningless variable for no benefit at all.

The question remains why `new int();` is allowed although the use of the literal `0;` is not. Yet again I do not *know* the answer but possible reasons could be

- since `new ClassName();` is allowed then `new int();` should be too
- creating an exception for the rule that "new object expressions can be used as a statement" would have little benefit but would have meant more work and more tests and more money spent

Comment: OK. Then why is it not allowed to write `new int[2];`? It should be related to invoking constructor I think, but it is not allowed. :-)

Comment: @TheLastError probably because `new int[2];` not a "new object expression" but a something like a "new array expression".